# How to run multiple tests(@test) on same session

Tags: java, testng

For below code i couldn't able to run all tests on same session.

Steps followed for run below code:
1. Right click class name -> Run As -> TestNg test
           Browser session is closed for each session. here i want to execute all tests without closing browser session.

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"browser", "pdpurl"})
public void setData(@Optional("")String browser, @Optional("")String pdpurl) {
    browserName = browser.isEmpty() ? "chrome" : browser;
    url = pdpurl.isEmpty() ? propDatas.getProperty(PDP_URL) : pdpurl; 
}

@Test
@Parameters("frame")
public void test1(@Optional("")String frame){
    new SendAndClaim(driver)
    .clickGiftNow()
    .switchFrame(frame);
}   

@Test(dependsOnMethods="test1")
public void test2() {
    new SendAndClaim(driver)
    .enterName()
    .enterMail()
    .enterFromName()
    .enterFromMail()
    .clickPayment();
}


public class Company extends GenericWrappers
public String browserName;
public String url;
public String dataSheetName;

@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(){
}

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(){
    loadObjects();
    loadDatas();
}
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(){
    invokeApp(browserName, url);
}

@AfterSuite
public void afterSuite(){
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest(){
    unloadObjects();
    unloadDatas();
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(){
    closeAllBrowsers();     
}
```

Comment: Currently where is the browser close method called?

Comment: I have extended that class name here. browser close method is located inside company class. 
public class SendAndAccept extends company

Comment: ok... but when is this called? afterclass? aftermethod?...

Comment: browser close is called on after method

Comment: call it in the AfterClass method...

Comment: I tried but it is not working. test1 session not closed and test2 started with new session.

Comment: then where is the code for opening the session? The BeforeClass in the query does not have that code or is it edited out?

Comment: Shouldn't `@BeforeClass` be put on a `public static` method?

Comment: @Grasshopper i have extended session code from different class file
public class SendAndAccept extends Company. I have added that class file above

Answer (score 0):

If this is your method, Call `closeAllBrowsers();` method in `@AfterSuite` method. So it will execute after completing all test cases.

Comment: i changed closeAllBrowsers(); into @AfterSuite but test2 is opened on new session. So there is no connectivity between test1 and test2

Comment: That might depends on the method closeAllBrowsers(); how you have handle it. Please check on it.

Comment: @Prakash - Do you mind editing your question and atleast showing us what your browser instantiation and browser cleanup look like ? We need to see how does your `closeAllBrowsers()` look like and where is your webdriver objects being created etc., Without that, its hard to say what is going wrong.